# Github Super Linter - C# Linter is not doing any style checks

Tags: c#, github-actions, super-linter, dotnet-format

I have set up Github super linter to lint C# files in my project. I added the rules in a .editorconfig file. But when I run the linter, I only get a bunch of whitespace errors and none of the styling or other errors. For e.g., I added a rule for member variables to start with `m_`. But it doesn't detect that as an error. Do I need to add any environment variable to do the style checks? When I went through the [dotnet format](https://github.com/dotnet/format) page, its mentioned that whitespace, style and analyzers will run simultaneously. But that doesn't happen in my case or it is not detecting the style issues.

Edit:

Here's the `.editorconfig`. Note this was exported from the source code using Rider

```
# top-most EditorConfig file
root = true

[*]
[*.cs]
indent_style = tab
charset = utf-8
end_of_line = lf
trim_trailing_whitespace = false

# Microsoft .NET properties
csharp_new_line_before_members_in_object_initializers = false
csharp_new_line_before_open_brace = accessors,anonymous_types,control_blocks,object_collection_array_initalizers
csharp_preferred_modifier_order = public, private, protected, internal, file, new, static, abstract, virtual, sealed, readonly, override, extern, unsafe, volatile, async, required:suggestion
csharp_style_prefer_utf8_string_literals = true:suggestion
csharp_style_var_elsewhere = true:suggestion
csharp_style_var_for_built_in_types = true:suggestion
csharp_style_var_when_type_is_apparent = true:suggestion
dotnet_naming_rule.private_constants_rule.import_to_resharper = as_predefined
dotnet_naming_rule.private_constants_rule.severity = warning
dotnet_naming_rule.private_constants_rule.style = upper_camel_case_style
dotnet_naming_rule.private_constants_rule.symbols = private_constants_symbols
dotnet_naming_rule.private_instance_fields_rule.import_to_resharper = as_predefined
dotnet_naming_rule.private_instance_fields_rule.severity = warning
dotnet_naming_rule.private_instance_fields_rule.style = m_upper_camel_case_style
dotnet_naming_rule.private_instance_fields_rule.symbols = private_instance_fields_symbols
dotnet_naming_rule.private_static_fields_rule.import_to_resharper = as_predefined
dotnet_naming_rule.private_static_fields_rule.severity = error
dotnet_naming_rule.private_static_fields_rule.style = lower_camel_case_style_1
dotnet_naming_rule.private_static_fields_rule.symbols = private_static_fields_symbols
dotnet_naming_rule.private_static_readonly_rule.import_to_resharper = as_predefined
dotnet_naming_rule.private_static_readonly_rule.severity = warning
dotnet_naming_rule.private_static_readonly_rule.style = upper_camel_case_style
dotnet_naming_rule.private_static_readonly_rule.symbols = private_static_readonly_symbols
dotnet_naming_rule.unity_serialized_field_rule.import_to_resharper = True
dotnet_naming_rule.unity_serialized_field_rule.resharper_description = Unity serialized field
dotnet_naming_rule.unity_serialized_field_rule.resharper_guid = 5f0fdb63-c892-4d2c-9324-15c80b22a7ef
dotnet_naming_rule.unity_serialized_field_rule.severity = warning
dotnet_naming_rule.unity_serialized_field_rule.style = lower_camel_case_style
dotnet_naming_rule.unity_serialized_field_rule.symbols = unity_serialized_field_symbols
dotnet_naming_style.lower_camel_case_style.capitalization = camel_case
dotnet_naming_style.lower_camel_case_style_1.capitalization = camel_case
dotnet_naming_style.lower_camel_case_style_1.required_prefix = _
dotnet_naming_style.m_upper_camel_case_style.capitalization = pascal_case
dotnet_naming_style.m_upper_camel_case_style.required_prefix = m_
dotnet_naming_style.upper_camel_case_style.capitalization = pascal_case
dotnet_naming_symbols.private_constants_symbols.applicable_accessibilities = private
dotnet_naming_symbols.private_constants_symbols.applicable_kinds = field
dotnet_naming_symbols.private_constants_symbols.required_modifiers = const
dotnet_naming_symbols.private_instance_fields_symbols.applicable_accessibilities = private
dotnet_naming_symbols.private_instance_fields_symbols.applicable_kinds = field
dotnet_naming_symbols.private_static_fields_symbols.applicable_accessibilities = private
dotnet_naming_symbols.private_static_fields_symbols.applicable_kinds = field
dotnet_naming_symbols.private_static_fields_symbols.required_modifiers = static
dotnet_naming_symbols.private_static_readonly_symbols.applicable_accessibilities = private
dotnet_naming_symbols.private_static_readonly_symbols.applicable_kinds = field
dotnet_naming_symbols.private_static_readonly_symbols.required_modifiers = static,readonly
dotnet_naming_symbols.unity_serialized_field_symbols.applicable_accessibilities = *
dotnet_naming_symbols.unity_serialized_field_symbols.applicable_kinds = 
dotnet_naming_symbols.unity_serialized_field_symbols.resharper_applicable_kinds = unity_serialised_field
dotnet_naming_symbols.unity_serialized_field_symbols.resharper_required_modifiers = instance
dotnet_style_parentheses_in_arithmetic_binary_operators = never_if_unnecessary:none
dotnet_style_parentheses_in_other_binary_operators = always_for_clarity:none
dotnet_style_parentheses_in_relational_binary_operators = never_if_unnecessary:none
dotnet_style_predefined_type_for_locals_parameters_members = true:suggestion
dotnet_style_predefined_type_for_member_access = true:suggestion
dotnet_style_qualification_for_event = false:suggestion
dotnet_style_qualification_for_field = false:suggestion
dotnet_style_qualification_for_method = false:suggestion
dotnet_style_qualification_for_property = false:suggestion
dotnet_style_require_accessibility_modifiers = for_non_interface_members:suggestion
```

I use the GHA example referenced in the [documentation](https://github.com/github/super-linter#example-connecting-github-action-workflow) for setting up mine and for local testing I use this docker [command](https://github.com/github/super-linter/blob/main/docs/run-linter-locally.md). I disabled validation for a bunch of other languages using the environment variables

```
VALIDATE_ARM=false
VALIDATE_CLANG_FORMAT=false
VALIDATE_CLOJURE=false
VALIDATE_CLOUDFORMATION=false
VALIDATE_COFFEESCRIPT=false
VALIDATE_CPP=false
VALIDATE_DART=false
VALIDATE_DOCKERFILE_HADOLINT=false
VALIDATE_ENV=false
VALIDATE_GHERKIN=false
VALIDATE_GITLEAKS=false
VALIDATE_JSCPD=false
VALIDATE_LATEX=false
VALIDATE_LUA=false
VALIDATE_OPENAPI=false
VALIDATE_PERL=false
VALIDATE_SCALAFMT=false
VALIDATE_SNAKEMAKE_LINT=false
VALIDATE_SNAKEMAKE_SNAKEFMT=false
VALIDATE_TEKTON=false
VALIDATE_TERRAFORM_FMT=false
VALIDATE_TERRAFORM_TERRASCAN=false
VALIDATE_TERRAFORM_TFLINT=false
VALIDATE_TERRAGRUNT=false
VALIDATE_TSX=false
```

Comment: Please [edit] in your `.edirconfig` showing that configuration.

Comment: In addition to your `.editorconfig`, please do include your relevant GHA workflow in your question. Thanks!

Comment: Updated questions with more details

Comment: Were you able to resolve the issue? Can you show us your github action YAML file?